# Map.filter() not returning expected output

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying the leetcode remove elements problem. The goal is to remove all the elements from an array equal to a certain value. For example if the `array = [3, 2, 2, 3]` and the `val = 3` the output array should be [2, 2].

My filter function seems to be producing the correct output based on the console log, but in the return statement it is something totally different.

Below is a copy of my code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {number}
 */
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    let filteredNums = nums.filter(element => { 
        return element !== val
    });
    console.log(filteredNums)
    return filteredNums;
};
```

Here is what I am getting for the output:

[image]

Is there something I am doing incorrect that I am missing?

Comment: You should use const instead of var to declare this function.

Comment: do you have a link to the question of leetcode?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, the problem seems to be a nuance of writing the test case correctly.

Comment: I just ran your code and the return value is correct.

Comment: If it is https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/ then you need to return the length of the array. Note in your code the `@return {number}`. It does not expect an array back

Comment: it looks like, your question is about removing items from the array and keeping the object reference to the given array `nums`. (i would answer, of the q is reopened.)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I am aware I was supposed to return the length, but when that wasn't working I realized that the output array wasn't giving me what I expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assuming to *remove* elements form the array, you could use a different approach by splicing the array.

By using [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), you need to iterate from the end of the array, because the index is changing for deleted elements.

Finally you need to return the new length of the array.

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {number}
 */

var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    let i = nums.length;
    
    while (i--) if (nums[i] === val) nums.splice(i, 1);

    return nums.length;
};

var array = [3, 2, 2, 3];

console.log(removeElement(array, 3));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Great answer, I upvoted it. The only thing to keep an eye on is that modifying arrays in place can complicate your app and make the debugging harder. If it is not a big performance issue, it is often better to return a new, updated array.

Answer (score 1):

- [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837856/6553328) is very good;
- We can also solve the problem without using built-in functions – especially for easy LeetCode questions that's somewhat important (for interviews, not the contests):

```
const removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    let lo = 0;
    let hi = nums.length - 1;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        if (nums[lo] === val) {
            swap(nums, lo, hi);
            hi -= 1;
        } else {
            lo += 1;
        }
    }

    return lo;
};

const swap = function(nums, left, right) {
    const temp = nums[left];
    nums[left] = nums[right];
    nums[right] = temp;
    return nums;
};

// console.log(removeElement(nums = [3,2,2,3], val = 3));
```

#### Disclaimer:

- Don't know JavaScript well;

Comment: Great answer, I upvoted it. It does make sense not to use built-ins during an interview, or use them only when your interviewer is OK with it, and even then one needs to know and be able to explain how to implement those built-ins if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works as intended:

```js
const removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    let filteredNums = nums.filter(element => { 
        return element !== val
    });
    console.log("From inside of the function:", filteredNums)
    return filteredNums;
};


const exampleArray = [3, 2, 2, 3];
const element = 3;

console.log("Original array before:", exampleArray)
const result = removeElement(exampleArray, element);
console.log("Returning array:", result);
console.log("Original array after:", exampleArray)
```

One thing that may trip you up is the fact that filteredNums **is not changing the incoming array**, instead it returns a copy of the original array without filtered out elements.